# Xamarin Forms - Change cursor colour and bottom border using XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to change the colour of the cursor and the bottom border of an `Entry` field using XAML. (It is pink in colour at the moment). Changing the font colour didn't help and I can't see anything informative in the IntelliSense either. Can someone please tell me how to do this in XAML? Thank you.

```
<Entry
    x:Name="editorEmailAddress"
    TextColor="Purple" />
```

In Android, it shows in pink.
[image]

Comment: You can't. you have to edit the resources file

Comment: @Alex Do you mean the styles.xml file in Xamarin.Android project? Can you please tell me how to do it, if it's not possible to do using XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `colorAccent` value in **styles.xml** (in *Xamarin.Android* project) will change the colour of the cursor and the bottom border of an `Entry` field.

```
<item name="colorAccent">#BA55D3</item>
```

Comment: I used <item name="colorControlActivated">#800080</item> in Xamarin Forms 4.7 to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material_theme/

follow the guidelines to resolve your problem.

or if you want to change it by Custom Render  than follow below link.

[Is it possible to change the colour of the line below / Border of a TextBox (Entry)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207168/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-line-below-border-of-a-textbox-ent)