# Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0 and Context

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Today I updated to [Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.5/2.5.0-sr1/) and saw, that I get the following warnings:

- From the Android sub-project:

  > Warning    CS0618  'Forms.Context' is obsolete: 'Context is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use a local context instead.'

How can I get the local context instead of `Forms.Context`? [Is the Android Context meant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353986/xamarin-forms-forms-context-is-obsolete)

- From the custom renderer:

  > Warning    CS0618  'ButtonRenderer.ButtonRenderer()' is obsolete: 'This constructor is obsolete as of version 2.5. Please use ButtonRenderer(Context) instead.'

In my `ButtonRenderer` I only have the `OnElementChanged()` method, so what should I change here? Simply add a `ButtonRenderer(Context)` constructor? I still get the warning, if I do this in my platform renderer class. Does anyone have an example? The [official documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) doesn't mention it and Google also doesn't bring some useful results, except the [open source code of `ButtonRenderer`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs). This change also concerns many other renderer classes.

Does anyone had experienced other changes, which brakes plugins and so on?

PS: Also I didn't found out, when `Device.Windows` was deprecated. Now I replaced it with `Device.UWP`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had this same issue for a `SearchBarRenderer` and all I needed to do to fix it was add a constructor like so:

```
public ShowSearchBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{
}
```

Hope that answers the second part of your question.

Comment: I had to also add `using Android.Content;`

Answer (score 21):

There are two questions here:

1. How do I update Custom Renderers to use a local context?
2. How can I access the current context now that `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` is obsolete?

## How to Update Custom Renderers

Add the overloaded Constructor to each custom renderer

Here is an example using a `ButtonRenderer`

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            //ToDo: Customize Button
        }
    }
}
```

## How to Access The Current Context

Install [Xamarin.Essentials NugGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/).

Now, you can call `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.AppContext` when you need to access the current activity.

Here's an example of how to open the App's Settings in Xamarin.Forms.

```cs
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeepLinks_Android))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class DeepLinks_Android : IDeepLinks
    {
        Context CurrentContext => Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.AppContext;

        public Task OpenSettings()
        {
            var myAppSettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ActionApplicationDetailsSettings, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + CurrentContext.PackageName));
            myAppSettingsIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    CurrentContext.StartActivity(myAppSettingsIntent);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(CurrentContext.ApplicationContext, "Unable to open Settings", ToastLength.Short);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

use `Android.App.Application.Context`

There is a discussion of this topic on the [Forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106938/context-is-obsolete-as-of-version-2-5)

Comment: Any downside to this? Direct copy and replace of Forms.Context? I'd like to avoid bringing in the plugin if at all possible. Thanks!

Comment: This will brake all controls that require AppCompat theme.