# Xamarin Entry bottom line color doesn`t change

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I am working on Android application. Right now I am creating MainPage where I insert `Entry` which has the bottom line as always. The bottom line on my previewer is `White` while on my phone it appears to be `Black`.

So to fix the issue I decided to play with renderers and see if I can fix it.
I created Class in App called `CustomEntryRenderer` which inherits from Entry.
Then I created Class in App.Android called `CustomEntryRednererAndroid` which is supposed to change the color of bottom entry line. But it doesn`t affect it. I tried doing the same with some custom renderers I found on the internet.

For example deleting bottom line didn`t affect the program as well:
[removing line](https://gist.github.com/dkudelko/42f2d5bc1c8b3aba1d3d)

Entry from MainPage.xaml:

```
<Entry 

        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        TextColor="Silver"         
        Placeholder="Write Your nickname"
        PlaceholderColor="Silver"

        />
```

CustomEntryRenderer:

```
 public class CustomEntryRenderer : Entry
{
}
```

CustomEntryRendererAndroid:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntryRenderer), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace App3.Droid
{
public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{

    public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
            Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        else
            Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.White, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
    }
}
```

}

[Top answer for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207168/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-line-below-border-of-a-textbox-ent)
And for some reason also in `CustomEntryRendererAndroid.cs` I had to use `Android.Graphic` instead of `Xamarin.Forms.Color`. But I dont think that is the issue.

I have been trying for a couple of hours now and can`t find the way out of this situation. 
Would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In xaml you are using the default `Entry` control and not your `CustomEntryRenderer` which is what your renderer is affecting. Also, you might want to rename it because it is not actually your renderer, but your custom control.

To resolve your issue you can either change your renderer `typeof(CustomEntryRenderer)` to `typeof(Entry)` to affect all Android entries in your app by default. For example, this worked for my test app for all Entries:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null) return;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                Control.BackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            else
                Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.White, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
    }
}
```

The other option is to switch your xaml code in `MainPage` to actually use your custom control. For example, `<local:CustomEntryRenderer/>`

Comment: Thanks for answer! I tried changing `typeof(CustomEntryRenderer)` to `typeof(Entry)` but after doing that and starting my app with Live Player. The xamarin Live just crashes. Every time I try and I tried it with different renderers. Also do You know why previewer shows different line color then app started on phone?

Comment: I updated my answer to be more specific. If you just change it to be Entry you can delete your `CustomEntryRender` class. Afterwards, I'd make sure to delete the bin and obj folder and rebuild your project. As for the Xamarin Live Previewer last time I tried using it it was still super buggy and is still in development so I'd just deploy directly to the device if possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed the issue and I had to deploy directly on my phone as well.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this in the **Styles.xml** repairs it globally

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#1BB8A3</item>"
```