# Set secondary color of all views

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

[image of an Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuKiW.png)

Like shown in the image above my secondary color for all my views is pink.
But I want it to be a different one.

Where can I set the Color globally?

Comment: Extends the view and create a renderer for that

Comment: Theme a Xamarin.Forms Application ,please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Entries that pink color is the color accent of the application

Which can be modified of course. [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241870/how-to-customize-coloraccent-when-changing-the-the.html)

But if you want a little more customization for this view and maybe others. You will have to use custom renderers. Here is another [question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38207168/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-line-below-border-of-a-textbox-ent)