# Bottom border on Entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

!!! This question is not about creating the border, but about customizing the length of it when it has been created !!!

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project, where I would like to change the color of the border below the Entry field on Android devices. Currently I have tried to do this using a Custom Renderer, and I am almost there, but it does not appear as I would like it to. The blue bottom border is slightly wider/longer than the Entry field, but on the regular Entry field the border and the Entry field are the same width/length. How can I customize my bottom border to fit the width/length of the Entry field?

The picture shows the regular Entry field on top, and the Entry with Custom Renderer at the bottom.

[Regular Entry field on top and Entry field with Custom Renderer at the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EapDS.png)

The following code is the XML for creating the bottom border natively in Android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape> 
            <stroke android:color="#33b5e5" android:width="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The following code is the Custom Renderer for the Entry

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using App.Company;
using App.Company.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace App.Company.Droid
{
    class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Lime);
                Control.Background = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.BottomBorder, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is the XAML defining the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Company;assembly=App.Company"
             x:Class="App.Company.Views.StylesTestPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- COLORS -->
            <Color x:Key="Rgray">#A8A8A8</Color>

            <!-- ENTRIES -->
            <Style x:Key="entryCustom"
                   TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="200" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="45" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="entryCustomGray"
                   TargetType="Entry"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource entryCustom}">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Rgray}" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Entry Placeholder="Entry placeholder text"
                   Style="{StaticResource entryCustomGray}">
            </Entry>
            <local:CustomEntry Placeholder="In Shared Code"
                                Style="{StaticResource entryCustomGray}">
            </local:CustomEntry>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Border Color of Entry in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822668/how-to-change-border-color-of-entry-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call below function in **OnElementChanged**.

```
    private void SetBorder(CustomEntry view)
    {
         if (view.HasBorder == false)
         {
               var shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
               shape.Paint.Alpha = 0;
               shape.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
               Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(shape);
         }
         else 
         {
               Control.SetBackground (originalBackground);
         }
   }
```