# Validation part in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I dont Know how to set the border color . if the user enter the wrong keyword then the border shows red color on it. let me know if anyone have this solution for this. I have attached sample image here. Thanks!

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkhRx.png)

i need exactly same like this.

Comment: Please share relevant code along with a description of your problem and what you've already tried to do to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check on button click event using regular expression for Password field and match your both text are same or not.

Code :

```
    public void btnclick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(string.ISNullOrEmpty(entrypassword.text))
    {
        lblerror1.text = "Password Required";
        return;
    }
    if(string.ISNullOrEmpty(entryconfirmpassword.text))
    {
        lblerror2.Text = "Confirm Password required";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(entrypassword.text.length <9)
        {
            lblerror1.Text = "Password must be 8 characters";
            return;
        }       
        if(entrypassword.text != entryconfirmpassword.text)
        {
            lblerror2.Text = "Passwords are not match";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // your button click code
        }       
    }       
}
```

There is also second option is `Triggers` of Entry.

Comment: Hi Thanks!. Is it possible to set a border outline color for ImageEntry

Comment: For that you have to use Entry Renderer. You can check for that code using this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37823390/6060754

Comment: @Muthukumarc, you could refer to the [XfxEntry](https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls)

Comment: @York Shen         Hi All Thanks for Your reply but i want a Border Effect . when if the Entry Is Empty then border color it shows Red otherwise it shows only default color.